# How do I make cli start with program name instead of path?

Tags: rust, command-line-interface

When I type `cargo run`, I want the cmd prompt to sit at

```
Project_ ->
```

and then await a command.

Currently, when I `cargo run`, it just sits on a blank line and waits for an input. Once I type something and press enter, my output is

```
test
Project_ -> test
```

How do I get the line that is awaiting a command to begin with

```
Project_ ->
```

and then await a command?

```
fn main() {
    let mut run = true;
    let mut stdin = io::BufReader::new(io::stdin()).lines();
    let stdout = io::stdout();
    let mut handle = stdout.lock();
    
    while run {
        handle.write_all(b"Project_ -> ");
        
        {
            let arg = stdin.next().unwrap().unwrap();
            println!("{:?}", arg);

            if arg == "exit" {
                run = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Removing `println!("{:?}", arg);` makes it so that `Project_ ->` isn't printed at all.

Pressing enter over and over again and then typing exit prints `Project_ ->` the number of times I pressed enter.

Comment: Sounds like you need to `flush()` the output.

Comment: why using a `run` flag when you can call `break` ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by wrapping handle in a BufWriter and using .flush() to print immediately.

```
fn main() {
    let mut run = true;
    let mut stdin = io::BufReader::new(io::stdin()).lines();
    let stdout = io::stdout();
    let mut handle = io::BufWriter::new(stdout.lock());

    while run {
        handle.write_all(b"Project_ -> ");
        handle.flush();

    
        let arg = stdin.next().unwrap().unwrap();
        // println!("{:?}", arg);
        if arg == "exit" {
            run = false
        }
```

Comment: You might not need `BufWriter` - standard output is buffered already, and `flush` is implemented on `StdoutLock` as part of `Write` trait - https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.StdoutLock.html#method.flush